# Build failed: unable to open file (in target '' in project '')(in target '')

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm trying to open a sample app from Prebid.

When I open the project from the PrebidDemo directory, I receive the error:
[image]

I'm attempting to open the project from the PrebidDemo directory:
https://github.com/prebid/prebid-mobile-ios/tree/master/example/Swift/PrebidDemo

Sorry for what may be a basic question, I'm new to Swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like an issue with cocoPods not being installed. If you install cocoPods that should resolve it for you.

Answer (score 1):

1. command on your terminal to install it.

   ```
   sudo gem install cocoapods-deintegrate
   ```
2. command on your terminal to install it.

   ```
   sudo gem install cocoapods-clean
   ```

3.Go to your project folder from terminal and type

```
    pod deintegrate
```

4. Again

   ```
   pod clean
   ```

5.delete the podfile manually or type in

```
rm Podfile
```

**Note: make sure you copy all the pod names before deleting**

6. follow the same procedure you do to install pod. paste all the pod name and then pod install